# Windows Phone: Define a GPS Path

Tags: c#, gps, windows-phone

I have an application with a List of geographic coordinates, right know I use these points to get a static map with the path they represent from the Google Maps Api.

[image]

What I wanted to do now was to use that List of points with the smartphone GPS, by doing so the user can still get the map without an Internet connection and he can follow the exact pretended path.

Can you recommend me a way of doing this? All the tutorials I have found so far only retrieve the current position of the user and none actually sends a path to the GPS .

Comment: What do you mean with sending a path to the GPS? Opening a GPS application showing your route? Implementing your own turn-by-turn application?

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to have the phone's GPS showing my route. By the way I am working on a project that gives directions to people in large facilities, like a university campus. And because of that the route is predefined and not calculated by the GPS.

Comment: Well, you can show the route on a map using a `MapPolyline`

Comment: anderZubi that can be helpful for my app.

Comment: You could draw the route using a MapPolyline with your list of points on the map control, and then put a pushpin or something on the user's current position, which you can get by using the location API